# unable to read the original url when host is specified

Tags: java, spring, http2

My code is running on localhost and i am hitting one of my urls as below

```
curl -k -vv --http1.1 "https://localhost:8443/versa/login" -H 'Host: google.com'
```

Now i m a trying to read the url in my code using following

```
StringBuffer url = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL();
```

The value is always as follows irrespective the protocol used is `HTTP/1.1` or `HTTP/2`

```
https://google.com/versa/login
```

How to read the original url here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Have a look at the output from curl - it should give the clue [I dropped the HTTPS to HTTP to simplify but same for HTTPS just more debug from CURL]

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
> GET /versa/login HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
```

The first two lines are just debug.  The next 4 is what is sent to the server .. See nothing about port or localhost ..

Comment: Thanks you Mr R , then can you suggest how to i solve Host Header attack if i am not able to determine my source host?

Comment: Firstly it's not an attack per-se ...   imagine you have multiple websites linked to the same IP the request needs to fully describe what it refers to - so if you have `foo.com` and `bar.com` on same IP then requests from a browser to either will differ based on URI and Host but will both come into via the same IP/port (by default)

Comment: In a production system - you are going to front-end the java with something else - nginx, apache, etc.  In apache, for instance, you define virtual hosts and what traffic they accept - anything else gets rejected. You define the URIs you want to end up at the Java engine and it only has to deal with things it's good at (running code), and not with all the other stuff - caching, proxying, serving up other content, etc.

Comment: NOW in a production HTTPS world you use certificates to authenticate servers & potentially clients.  In this case the channel is authenticated BEFORE anything is sent - so if you can work out which certificate the channel was authenticated against then perhaps you can detect the Host case...